# Why is my payload undefined when I have a commit in an axios call

Tags: vuejs2, axios, vuex

I have a action in my vuex store that makes a post call and commits the data response to a new array.

The issue I am having is that my payload is undefined when I have the commit call active in the axios response. When I take it out the payload has the proper data.

This is the call with the commit:

```js
async addToCategories ({ commit },categories, payload) {
        //commit('createCategories', categories);
        const  formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('CategoryName', payload);

        await axios({
                method: 'post',
            url: 'https://localhost:5001/api/Categories',
            data: formData,
            headers: { 'Content-Type': undefined }
            })
            .then((response) =>  {
                console.warn('Axios response', response);
                commit('createCategories', response.data.Categories);
            })
            .catch((response) => {
                console.warn(response);
            });

      }
```

What I cannot understand or figure out is why the payload is undefined when I have the commit call in the action, but populates with out the commit. Is there a way I can do this and have the payload data to be able to submit to the backend or how can I separate this to get the results that I need?

I have tried a dispatch to a mutation for the commit as well and again the payload is undefined.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Update:
Screen grab of the axios response data
[image: axios response data]

Comment: What does `console.warn('Axios response', response);` print in the console? If `response.data` is defined, can you provide what that is, too?

Comment: A Vuex action only takes two arguments, the context and the payload. You currently have 3. You can't pass multiple arguments to an action, you need to wrap them in a single object instead.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue by just taking out the category parameter from the action and all works as expected now . thanks for taking a look at it

```
async addToCategories ({ commit }, payload) {
        //commit('createCategories', categories);
        const  formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('CategoryName', payload);

        await axios({
                method: 'post',
            url: 'https://localhost:5001/api/Categories',
            data: formData,
            headers: { 'Content-Type': undefined }
            })
            .then((response) =>  {
                console.warn('Axios response', response);
                commit('createCategories', response.data.Categories);
            })
            .catch((response) => {
                console.warn(response);
            });

      }
```